# Process Scheduler Update

Tags: c

I'm not good at coding and I have been forced to take an OS class (Q _ Q).
I'm not expert with C or C++. So I'm asking for help with **HOMEWORK**.

What I have so far as a code:

1) reading from a text file  ( works perfectly fine)

ex) input >>

```
   p[1] arrive at time 2

   p[2] arrive at time 1 block 2 1
```

2) telling the different between running process and blocked process ( works perfectly fine)

3) it will find how long each process will blocked ( works perfectly fine)

---

This is the part I need help with.

```
//RUN SIMULATION
cpuTimer=0; //each increment represents one quantum.
while(jobq != NULL || readyq != NULL || processing_head != NULL && cpuTimer < 1000)
{
    cpuTimer++;
    my_queue* current = jobq;

    while(current!=NULL)
    {
        //task has arrived and is can be moved to readyQ
        if (current->this_task.arrival_time <= cpuTimer)
        {
            cout << "ADDING TO READYQ: " <<current->this_task.taskid << endl;
            removeQ(&jobq, &current, &job_tail);
            pushQ(&readyq, &current, &ready_tail);
            current = jobq;
        }
        else
            current = current->next;
    }
    // scheduler update here
}
```

My question is how can I update the scheduler so it can output step by step status of each process. my objective to make the output to look like this:

```
 p[2] arrive 1
 p[1] arrive 2 
 p[1] done
 p[2] blocked 2 for 1 CPUTIME
 p[2] done
```

I did use Google and I also looked at all the other questions that had similar title. But I wanted to get more help.

Comment: Answer will probably be very different in C and C++. Recommend picking one.

Comment: If I had to pick 1 I would go with C. I'm more familiar with it.

Comment: I will be grateful if you guys give me some hints. My objective to not get a full code but at least come up with the logic